# When I want to use hangfire server with redis pro, I have an exception

Tags: redis, hangfire

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer StackExchange.Redis.IRedisAsync.get_Multiplexer()'.
at Hangfire.Pro.Redis.RedisStorage.GetMasterEndpoint()
at Hangfire.Pro.Redis.RedisStorage.ToString()
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer..ctor(BackgroundJobServerOptions options, JobStorage storage, IEnumerable`1 additionalProcesses, IJobFilterProvider filterProvider, JobActivator activator, IBackgroundJobFactory factory, IBackgroundJobPerformer performer, IBackgroundJobStateChanger stateChanger) at Hangfire.HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireServer(IApplicationBuilder app, BackgroundJobServerOptions options, IEnumerable`1 additionalProcesses, JobStorage storage)
at UlysOpusApi.Configuration.Hangfire.HangfireMiddlewareConfiguration.UseHangfire(IApplicationBuilder app, HangfireConfiguration configuration) in C:\Work\interface_opus_digital\UlysOpusApi\Main\4_Infrastructure\UlysOpusApi.Configuration\HangFire\HangfireMiddlewareConfiguration.cs:line 17
at UlysOpusApi.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger logger, IHangfireService hangfireService, IOptions`1 swaggerConfiguration, IOptions`1 hangfireConfiguration) in C:\Work\interface_opus_digital\UlysOpusApi\Main\1_DistributedInterfaceLayer\UlysOpusApi.Web\Startup.cs:line 95
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoRegisterMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app) in E:\BA\56\s\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection\AutoRegisterMiddleware.cs:line 46
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Comment: I target .NET CORE 2.2, hangfire.pro.redis 2.2.1, hangfire.pro 1.7.14

Comment: indeed my distribution contains StackExchange.Redis package version 1.2.6. But I don’t understand why when I add UseRedistorage function to hangfire, at the runtime middleware raise an exception :
Exception thrown: ‘System.MissingMethodException’ in Hangfire.Pro.Redis.dll
An exception of type ‘System.MissingMethodException’ occurred in Hangfire.Pro.Redis.dll but was not handled in user code
Method not found: ‘StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer StackExchange.Redis.IRedisAsync.get_Multiplexer()’.